# Full height fluid image and div at one line. Div must take remaining horizontal space

Tags: android, css, internet-explorer-9, fluid-layout, aspect-ratio

Here is a div and transparent gif used as left margin with height-related width.
For example, if the window height is 480px, "margin" would be 48px.

So, how can I make content div take remaining width?
Solution must be non-js and IE9 & Android compatible.

N.B. image have 'display: table-cell', because seems only this way it can shrink, not only grow...

```
<--------------------- 100% WINDOW WIDTH ---------------->
,--------------------------------------------------------, ^
||                     ||                |               | |
||     IMG 1x10 px     ||  CONTENT DIV   |  FREE SPACE   | |
|| display: table-cell ||                |               | | 100% WINDOW HEIGHT 
||   height 100 %      ||  height 100 %  |               | |
||                     ||                |               | |
'--------------------------------------------------------' ь
```

Almost working solution: http://jsfiddle.net/koutsenko/g3fxh3k6/8/ 
Works as expected when running standalone html, not in fiddle. 
But has issues: at small heights "margin image" have additional margin.

**UPD**: I've one this task using javascript. Seems It's impossible to solve this task with only old CSS (without vh units).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be misunderstanding your question, but I think you mean how do you get the content div to take the rest of the row (regardless of what's in the left box).

I think the solution has a few steps (assuming you can adjust the markup):

1. Put the image into a div and apply `display: table-cell` to that instead of directly to the image.
2. Whatever div/container is wrapping around *both* cells needs a `display: table`.
3. The "content div" on the right side *also* needs a `display: table-cell` set.

When using `display: table` and `table-cell`, it's best to use regular markup to mimic the structure of actual HTML `table` elements.

**Note 1:** If you are just using the image to create a margin, then consider using CSS padding/margin to do that instead of the old-fashioned transparent GIF trick. I wasn't really clear on why you were doing this, but just in case!

**Note 2:** If this doesn't solve your problem, please supply a JSFiddle, and I'd be happy to revisit! Good luck :)

Comment: Yes, the content div must take the rest of row, http://jsfiddle.net/koutsenko/g3fxh3k6/ . The JS snippet used also causes browser reflow, it is sometimes necessary for fluid image. **2Note1** : In CSS, both vertical and horizontal margins calculated from **width** of container. But I need a left margin related to **height** of container. **2Note2** : I tried your advices, but can't sync image and wrapper-cell dimensions. Can you update jsfiddle?

Comment: Added some details to schema, it's important that table with "fluid margin" must take 100% window height.

Comment: Almost done - http://jsfiddle.net/koutsenko/g3fxh3k6/8/ . If I move the code  from jsfiddle to standalone html, it works as requested. But still have some bugs - "margin image" is getting strange additional margin in case of low browser height.

Comment: I see what you are seeing (there is a gap that appears at small browser sizes).

I think the reason is that the `<img>` is being affected by the fontSize change in JS along with the actual type. (Sort of like using `<img>` as a `display: inline` element, which causes spacing gaps). This gives it some minimum width that I can't shake.

Comment: It may also be a browser-imposed min-width on table-cells and `display: table-cell` elements. This Fiddle wraps an extra `div` around the `<img>` with a background color to highlight the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/g3fxh3k6/9/

Comment: Seems that in test case, bug reproduces only if content is a set of short words separated by spaces and fit into one string. Using two-string or longer content causes bug disappear. But, if it is a very long piece of text, layout breaks completely - very large font size. In sum, content div requires some additional style tweaks. What do you think, how exactly can this be done?

Comment: Not sure. Backing up a bit, is this definitely the *most* efficient way to get the layout you want? What you are requesting might not be possible without using JavaScript to manually read/set the heights and widths for all the elements.

Comment: If you have an overall layout that you are trying to achieve, maybe you can refactor your markup and achieve the same look with a different structure. Even if we **do** get this solution working, it feels very fragile. Also, relying so heavily on obscure CSS patterns like this may make browser-testing a nightmare. :-( just my $0.02.

Comment: Thanks. I've one this task using javascript. 
Seems It's impossible to solve this task with only old CSS (without vh units).

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Good luck with the rest of the site!